# How to do parallel search of a file ? (i want to search a file in one million files by parallaly )?

Tags: unix, grep, xargs, gnu-parallel

How to do parallel search of a file ? (i want to find a file in one million files)

By using this command to do the above operation

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P` number_of_processes grep my_pattern

it gave  Grep:No such file or directory,

what actually this command doing ?

how to do parallel search of a file? (even i tried **find . -type f | parallel -j+1 grep my_pattern**  )

Answer (score 2):

It is highly unlikely that your disk system is *not* the bottleneck and parallelizing I/O will often cause your disk system to slow down.

So this is probably the fastest:

```
find . | grep pattern
```

But on the off chance that your disk system is faster than your CPUs then this should work:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 | grep pattern
find . -type d -maxdepth 3 | parallel 'find {} | grep pattern'
```

Adjust '3' to fit your filesystem layout.